# Help with proof; Pre-image of a continuous function around a maximum is open.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

Suppose a function $u$ is defined in an open and connected set $D$ and has maximum value $c$. Then if $u$ is not constant in D then the set $\{u(z) < c \mid z \in D\}$ is non-empty and open.

This was claimed in the attached proof. Can anyone help me see why this is true? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the open interval $-\infty < x < c + 1$; since that's an open set, and preimages of open sets under continuous maps are open, its preimage, $H$, under $u$, is open. Since $\Omega$ is open as well, we have that $\Omega \cap H$ is open, which is what's claimed.

Comment: How are we sure that that interval is in the image of u?

Comment: It does't *have* to be in the image of $u$, merely in the codomain (which is $\mathbb R$). In fact, it's surely *not* in the image of $u$, because it contains $c + \frac{1}{2}$, while $c$ is the max of $u$. Perhaps you should review the definition of continuity, because tricks like these can be really useful.